# What is the easiest way to compare Java POJO

Tags: java, json, jackson, pojo

I have a class

```
public class A
{
    @Nonnull
    private final String m_a;

    @CheckForNull
    private final B m_b;

    @Nonnull
    private final List<C> m_c;

    @JsonCreator
    public A(
        @JsonProperty("a") @Nonnull final String a,
        @JsonProperty("b") @CheckForNull final B b,
        @JsonProperty("c") @Nonnull final List<C> c
    )
    {
        m_a = a;
        m_b = b;
        m_c = checkNotNull(c);
    }

    // getters ...
}
```

How would you recommend to compare if two A instances are equal?

I can use Jackson to serialize the JSON to a String (`.writeValueAsString`) and compare, but that is not cheap. Is it better if I override `equals` and `hashcode` and compare every field instead? What does it look like then?

Comment: override `equals()` and `hashCode()` is usually the solution which makes more sense

Comment: Most IDE's can generate an `equals()` and `hashCode()` for you.

Comment: Or, also not cheap, but definitely cheaper than converting to JSON: `if (other == null) return false; A that = (A)other; return Objects.equals(Arrays.asList(a, b, c), Arrays.asList(that.a, that.b, that.c));` (_please don't do this_) – and always override `hashCode` if you provide a custom `equals` implementation

Comment: you'll have to make sure that `C` is also a comparable object when comparing the `c` lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `equals()` and `hashCode()` in class `A` and `C`, then you can compare two instances by `A1.equals(A2)`

And there are bunch of plugins that can generate them for you, [example if you are using Intellij](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6875-equals-and-hashcode-deluxe-generator).